# Shortcut for address path in Windows

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer, shortcuts

How do I create a shortcut for a path address which I can then use in Windows File Explorer's address bar?

Rather than navigate through the filesystem structure every time, I want to do this:

1. Open Windows File Explorer with <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>

   - go to address bar with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
2. Type for example `_ng` which will automatically open the folder `C:\users\myuser\projects\open\new-garden`

I know there is a workaround to create an environment variable but then I have to use `%` which is not so fast.

Answer (score 0):

> type for example `_ng` which will automatically open folder

The closest you can get to this will be to define a user environment variable named **_ng** and set it to the value `C:\users\myuser\projects\open\new-garden`. Then to use it you'd type `%_ng%` into the Explorer address bar. To make it even faster to type, give the environment variable a single-letter name, such as `G`.

**Alternate Solutions**

- Create an entry for the folder in the Favorites section of Explorer in the left pane. You can access your folder with a single click.
- Create a shortcut to your folder and pin it to the Taskbar. This however doesn't give you quick access to your folder from within the Open/Save dialogs of programs.
- Map a drive letter such as G: to your folder. Then typing `G:` into the address bar will take you to that folder. However, you'll be accessing content through that drive letter, not the original folder path.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Using PATH variables is not so good solution for me. The reason is that keyboard layout for my language has `%` on really annoying place - I have to press `Alt-Gr + 5`.

Comment: @RonDo Just to clarify, I'm not talking about modifying the PATH variable; however your point is valid if use of `%` is problematic. Unfortunately, that's the only way to create a shortcut that can be used directly from Explorer's address bar. Otherwise you must use one of the alternate approaches.

Comment: I added another possible alternate idea.

Comment: thanks again. Exactly, it is called environment variable, not PATH variable - this is a lapsus. I corrected now in the question. I'll take a look at the added alternate idea and test how it works for me.